# Oracle Font Error incorrectly

Tags: sql-server, oracle, character-encoding, globalization

I have two Servers, one Oracle Server at IP 10.92.92.92, one SQL server at IP 10.92.92.93.
In Oracle Server, I am using Arial font to store database and it view correctly.
Now, I want to push database from Oracle Server to SQL server by Linked Server, As a result It views incorrect ly from SQL server, what errors happen?

When I use statement very simple such as: SELECT * FROM  SERVERXX..SERVER119.TABLENAME it also views incorrectly, Please help me with this?

Thank You everybody!

Comment: I cannot downvote this enough. This post does not make any sense.

Comment: I am not good at English, but I think everybody can understand it, 
Please help me!

Comment: It does not currently make any sense. The database does not have a font; the client application (e.g. SQL Developer) does, is that what you mean? I still don't see what that has to do with anything. 'Views incorrectly' is not enough to go on - is the SQL Server client just using a different font? Is it not showing some characters properly? The only guess I can make is that this is related to the character sets you're using in the two databases; if so you'll need to provide that information. But more importantly tell us what is actually wrong, with sample output and what you expect to see.

Comment: Your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12596130/266304) suggests it is a character set/encoding problem, but I can't tell if it's exactly the same.

Comment: I hope those aren't your real IP addresses.  In any case, they're completely irrelevant.  Why not post something useful, like database versions?

Comment: @user1654046, for future reference: if you don't get a satisfactory answer for your question, don't just raise another question - go back and edit your original question with more details (or at least add comments saying what's confusing you).

Answer (score 4):

A font is a client-side mechanism for rendering text on a screen.  Databases do not have fonts.  What they do have is character sets, which are protocols for translating code into characters.  Only ASCII 0-127 are standard.  Beyond that, how the client interprets a character value such as `230` depends entirely on the character set.

When transfering data from one database to another the *data doesn't change*.  But if the character sets are different and the receiving character set is not a super-set of the source character set the encodings will be garbled.

Find out more about [character sets in Oracle here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch1overview.htm#NLSPG001).
I'm not very familir with SQL Server but the equivalent feature in MSSQL appears to be Collation. [Find out more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx).

Comment: +1 for surprisingly good answer to a question I couldn't make any sense of.